# How to uninstall kerio vpn client?

Tags: command-line, uninstall

I want to delete this problem(uninstall kerio vpn client)
It appears every time I want to update/install an app
[image: screen shot of image]

Comment: Ubuntu-version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kerio VPN client is not a application from the official Ubuntu mirrors. This implies, that you have installed this package by your self. From the Kerio VPN client [installation guide](https://support.keriocontrol.gfi.com/hc/en-us/articles/360015190599-Configuring-Kerio-Control-VPN-Client-for-Linux), the Kerio package must be installed via `dpkg -i` and there are not official repos.

To remove the package, search for the installed package via `dpkg`

```
$ dpkg -l | grep -i kerio
```

The output will be something like:

```
ii  kerio-control-vpnclient-###-linux     1.2.3       amd64
```

Then remove this package with:

```
$ sudo apt-get --purge --yes remove kerio-control-vpnclient-xxx
```

by replacing the package name with the output of `dpkg -l`.